# JQuery AJAX not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have following code working nicely on all browsers but IE 7...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#homenews').load('http://domain.co.uk/investor/test_releases.php .newspost:lt(2)')
 });
 </script>
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: can you show the HTML that caused the problem?

Comment: I have cheated... I just put the HTML i needed in a PHP include and it seems to work. However...it still doesnt work in IE7. Even if the PHP include only contains text..

Comment: I see an space on the url after php is that correct, you can try to escape it

Comment: The space works fine in IE8. But the thing that is causing the problem is :lt(2). Without this and the .newspost it works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that IE7 could caching your code, when you use load jQuery function.

You can try to read this blog post, solving the issue:

http://zacster.blogspot.it/2008/10/jquery-ie7-load-url-problem.html